# Lumenworks Fast CsvReader - Exception error reading tab delimit file due to quote character

Tags: c#, csv, lumenworks

I'm using Lumenworks Fast CsvReader and the exception error occurred while reading the Kelley Blue Book's file:

> The CSV appears to be corrupt near record '1281' field '5 at position '1169'

The file is tab delimited. In there I found double quotes was used but I don't see how to escape it and resume normally because it's tab delimited data.

```
--Characters in Text File--
12345    2013    RAV4 "Sport" Sport Utility 4D    2

--Source Code--
using(CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filePath), false, '\t', '"', '"', '#', LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.ValueTrimmingOptions.QuotedOnly))
{
}
```

I tried a number of different CsvReader setting with no luck. What do you use that works great? I do not have that much trouble with comma delimited files.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It said "The CSV appears to be corrupt near record '1281' field '5 at position '1169'."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is  a mssing closing bracket behind the `StreamReader`:

```
using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filePath), false, '\t', '"', '"', '#', LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
{
    int fieldCount = csvReader.FieldCount;
    while (csvReader.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Column {0}: {1}", i + 1, csvReader[i]);
    }
}
```

I have tested it with your line above (forced tab as delimiter in the file) and it worked.

Output was:

```
Column 1: 12345
Column 2: 2013
Column 3: RAV4
Column 4: Sport
Column 5: Sport Utility
Column 6: 4D
Column 7: 2
```

**Update**, according your comment and the provided text-file:

This csv-reader enables to handle `FillError` and `ParseError` exceptions raised by invalid or corrupt data. So you handle them to get more informations and for logging purposes.

For example:

```
void csv_ParseError(object sender, ParseErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // if the error is that a field is missing, then skip to next line
    if (e.Error is MissingFieldCsvException)
    {
        //Log.Write(e.Error, "--MISSING FIELD ERROR OCCURRED!" + Environment.NewLine);
        e.Action = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
    }
    else if (e.Error is MalformedCsvException)
    {
        //Log.Write(e.Error, "--MALFORMED CSV ERROR OCCURRED!" + Environment.NewLine);
        e.Action = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
    }
    else
    {
        //Log.Write(e.Error, "--UNKNOWN PARSE ERROR OCCURRED!" + Environment.NewLine);
        e.Action = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
    }
}
```

You need to listen to this event:

```
csvReader.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
csvReader.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
csvReader.ParseError += csv_ParseError;
```

I have recognized that it doesn't work to use `"` as quoting character with your text-file since some fields contain data like `RAV4 "Sport" Sport Utility 4D`. So the field itself contains the quoting character. Instead you don't need one at all since no fields are quoted. So don't provide one in the constructor or set it as `'\0'`. Then this runs without a problem:

```
using(var rd  = new StreamReader(filePath))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(rd, false, '\t', '\0', '\0', '#', ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
{
    csvReader.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
    csvReader.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
    csvReader.ParseError += csv_ParseError;
    csvReader.SkipEmptyLines = true;
    int fieldCount = csvReader.FieldCount;
    while (csvReader.ReadNextRecord())
    {
       var fields = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
        {
            fields.Add(csvReader[i]);
        }
        lines.Add(fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Lumenworks are you using?  I'm using v3.8.0.   I'm unable to attach the text file for anyone to test to see if error will occur or not.

Comment: Me too. Why can't you upload a file somewhere? You can paste the link here or in your question.

Comment: Nice!!!  It works great!!  I never heard of using \0.  Glad to have learned this.   I'm familiar with the csv_ParseError() function and using it as delegate.  :-)   Thanks a million for your help!!!!