# CsvHelper Parser.Read() not splitting columns

Tags: c#, csvhelper

For some to me unknown reason the `csvHelper.parser.read()` method returns a string array with only one entry containing the entire row.

The `csv-file` looks like this:

> Name;Vorname;Alter
>
> Petersen;Peter;18
>
> Heinzen;Heinz;19

The code is like this:

```
using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default)))
{
    String[] cells = reader.Parser.Read();
    // cells = {"Name;Vorname;Alter"} (length = 1)
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or how do I get it to output an array of strings with three entries?

Edit:

CsvHelper: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

**expected result:**

`cells = {"Name", "Vorname", "Alter"} (length = 3)`

Comment: Example: [CsvReader](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21605485/3060520)

Comment: What is your expected result? What do you mean by: "array of strings with three entries"?

Comment: The CS in CSV stands for 'Comma Separated'. You didn't link to the class in question (What CsvHelper are we talking about), but most likely that class allows you to define your (non-standard) semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i feel stupid now...

Change the `reader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";`

Thanks [Benjamin Podszun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59492/benjamin-podszun) for getting me on the right track